# How to align Button to parent bottom in Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have simple layout containing ImageView, TextView and Button.

What I want to achieve is Imageview and TextView are in separate RelativeLayout centered inside parent and Button is under Imageview and TextView but it should align parent bottom, but it doesnt work like that. It is not aligned to bottom but hovering between bottom parent and relative layout above.

How to achieve this?

Here is a picture representation of how it should looks like:

[image]

If I add `android:layout_below="@+id/order_footer_image_text_layout"` :

[image]

Whole XML (order_list_footer_layout should be visible if recyclerview is empty... thats why they are overlapping)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_round"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolBarContent"
            layout="@layout/order_toolbar_layout" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_corners"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/order_list_footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/order_footer_image_text_layout"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/order_footer_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/orderTabFooter_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/image_order" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_footer_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/order_footer_image"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/order_footer_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorItemMinor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/food_list_top_row_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/order_choice_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/order_button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/order_button_padding_TOP_BOTTOM"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/order_button_padding_START_END"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/order_button_padding_START_END"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_button_padding_TOP_BOTTOM"
            android:background="@drawable/order_button_background_void"
            android:text="Choose Food"
            android:textAppearance="@style/VoidLoginButtonTextAppearance" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:gravity="center"` from top most `RelativeLayout` . That is causing all the childs of the relative layout to align center, if it is in `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Add in your xml of button

```
android:layout_below="@+id/order_list_footer_layout"
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It will make button "fat" it will just increase height

Comment: I'm sorry, and this: "order_list_footer_layout", instead of the other one

Answer (score 0):

```
            `<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/order_list_footer_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:id="@+id/order_footer_image_text_layout"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/order_footer_image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/order_footer_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/order_footer_image"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="test" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/order_choice_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`enter code here`
                        android:text="Button"/>

                </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Remove the line "android:gravity="center"" from the parent Relative Layout

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/order_list_footer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"  // remove this line
android:orientation="vertical">
......
```

Other thing is as it is